# Authentication and Authorization in React app

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In a .NET app I can add authentication and authorization using web.config and/or IIS. I can also use `[Authorize (Roles = "RoleABC")]` in a MVC app's controller or action. And even extend the `AuthorizationAttribute`

I'm looking into creating a React app for intranet use, and reading these tutorials ([ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)), but can't find authentication/authorization details.

Even though the app will be Single Page App, I still would like to authenticate and authorize users for certain options within the app, just like I can do in MVC app.

Is the only option to do that way is creating Blazor app instead?

Answer (score 0):

For authentication and authorization, you should use auth tokens (like JWT). Your backend should create an auth token when a client logs in to the system and sends it to the client. Your server also should send the authenticated user information to the client (react app) so that you can render correct pages according to the user type. For example, you can render the admin page for an admin type of user, and the guest page for a guest type of user. You can save this user data as JSON in Redux. Hence you can access the user data from any component of your react. Also, in your backend, you must restrict the endpoints according to the auth token which is sent by the client. In the backend of my app, I follow the below steps:

```
Authentication check -> Authorization check -> controller (endpoint) -> result
```

Answer (score 0):

React isn't opinionated on this, so it's up to you to design the implementation. A basic way to do this is:

1. Log in and obtain an authorized JWT token from the backend and include the account ID when you sign it
2. Store the JWT token in localStorage, store the account info in Redux
3. Conditionally limit routes based on account info (ie. admin group) on the front end
4. Have every auth-required API call include the JWT token in the `x-auth-token` header, then on the backend use middleware to check if it's still valid. You can then also decode the account ID in order to check its privileges so that you can limit API access

This may be helpful: https://medium.com/@faizanv/authentication-for-your-react-and-express-application-w-json-web-tokens-923515826e0#5f52

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you still need this - I personally feel we should have something bridging the authZ gap between server and client to make it easy. So I spent a few days on a github project for this purpose, here it is: [authzyin](https://github.com/sidecus/authzyin).

What I tried to do is to leverage policy based authorization from asp.net core - which I think it's very cool - and automatically bring the same definition to the client to use in React via hooks.

For authentication I am using msal.js against AAD - so authN is done on the client and jwt bearer token auth is used for all requests.

It has a client lib and a server lib which can be used together or separately. Of course it might still be lacking some features - please feel free to take it as a reference (contribution is also welcome).